# Identifying IMacros version

Tags: excel, imacros, vba

I want to add a little Excel vba script to identify if a user is has iMacros version 11.. In the past, we used the script below to identify if the user was on version 6 or 7 (I pulled this out of an old macro). I've tried to modify it to check for version 11. However, V11exe is always false and I need it to be true if the user has version 11. Currently, our users have version 10.3 or 11. The macro works for 11 but not 10.3 so I want to add this to the beginning of the macro and it will stop if v11exe is false and display a popup that you must have version 11 to use this macro. Any suggestions? Thanks of your help........

```
Sub iMacVersion()

v6Path = False
v6exe = False
v7Path = False
v7exe = False
v11Path = False
v11exe = False

Set ObjScr = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

v6Path = ObjScr.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\iMacros")
v7Path = ObjScr.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\iOpus\iMacros")
v11Path = ObjScr.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\Ipswitch\iMacros")
If v6Path = True Then v6exe = ObjScr.FileExists("C:\Program Files\iMacros\iMacros.exe")
If v7Path = True Then v7exe = ObjScr.FileExists("C:\Program Files\iOpus\iMacros\iMacros.exe")
If v11Path = True Then v11exe = ObjScr.FileExists("C:\Program Files\Ipswitch\iMacros\iMacros.exe")

Set ObjScr = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you can simply use the [`iimGetInterfaceVersion()`](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimGetInterfaceVersion()) function without extra lines of code.

Comment: @Shugar...........Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm going to give that a try and see if it will work for me........

Comment: @Shugar............This is looking promising.  I have tested it on 2 different machines (version 10.3 /  version 11) and get 2 different numbers.  I'm asking several people to test it to see if there is consistency with these numbers.  If so, I have the solution that I need.  Thanks for your help...

Comment: Nice to hear. Good luck!